# Why does PriorityQueue do (k - 1) >>> 1?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, priority-queue

I was studying PriorityQueue in Java.
When I looked into `offer` method, couldn't find out why using `(k - 1) >>> 1` in `siftUpComparable` method. 
Here is the source code:

```
public boolean offer(E e) {
    if (e == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    modCount++;
    int i = size;
    if (i >= queue.length)
        grow(i + 1);
    size = i + 1;
    if (i == 0)
        queue[0] = e;
    else
        siftUp(i, e);
    return true;
}

private void siftUp(int k, E x) {
    if (comparator != null)
        siftUpUsingComparator(k, x);
    else
        siftUpComparable(k, x);
}

private void siftUpComparable(int k, E x) {
    Comparable<? super E> key = (Comparable<? super E>) x;
    while (k > 0) {
        int parent = (k - 1) >>> 1; // what's the purpose of this line?
        Object e = queue[parent];
        if (key.compareTo((E) e) >= 0)
            break;
        queue[k] = e;
        k = parent;
    }
    queue[k] = key;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's guaranteed that `k > 0`, that line could just as well have been `(k - 1) >> 1`. The `>>` and `>>>` operators shift right by the number of bits given as the right-hand operand. Shifting by 1 is exactly the same as dividing by 2, so this is computing `parent = (k - 1) / 2` (with integer truncation), but doing it a little faster.

The difference between `>>` and `>>>` is what happens with negative numbers: `>>` fills on the left with the current value of the sign bit while `>>>` always fills with zero.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, it gave me a clear understanding of how `offer()` works

Answer (score 1):

It is getting the index of the parent element of the `k-th` element in the binary heap.

It is bit-shifting way for saying

```
int parent = (k-1)/2
```